# цветовая анимация добавляемых элементов

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Есть код который добавляет на страницу новые элементы с помощью ajax. Хочу что бы новые элементы выделялись цветом на фоне старых и в дальнейшем с помощью анимации цвет плавно превращался в цвет старых элементов. Подскажите как это реализовать?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function check(){
            var u=$('#body tr:first').data('u');
            $.get("ajax.php?u="+u, function(data){
                var d = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if(d.success>0){
                    $('#body').prepend(d.html);
                }
            });
        }
        setInterval(function(){check()}, 5000);
    });
```

этим кодом чекаются новые элементы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну примерно так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function check(){
      var u=$('#body tr:first').data('u');
      $.get("ajax.php?u="+u, function(data){
         var d = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         if(d.success>0){
            var e = $(d.html).css({backgroundColor: 'red'});
            $('#body').prepend(e);
            setTimeout(function() {
               $(e).animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 10000);
            }, 10000);
         }
      });
   }
   setInterval(function(){check()}, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Интересная идея, но на этой странице не использую css. Нарыл такую функцию jquery ui `.animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 10000);` ее и хочу прикрутить

Comment: в `d.html` содержится `<tr>...</tr>` - строки таблицы

Comment: @user193361, я изменил ответ. Можете посмотреть и опробовать

Comment: мне кажется `setTimeout` внутри условия лишний, поправьте если не так

Comment: `setTimeout` создаёт паузу перед плавным изменением цвета на "обычный". Можете его убрать. Это по желанию

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [highlight](http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/) из jQuery UI:

```js
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "highlight" );
});
```

```css
 #toggle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Кликните здесь чтобы скрыть/показать квадрат</p>
<div id="toggle"></div>
```